# Post request to Yelp API asking for parameter that has been provided

Tags: python, post, yelp

Trying to send a `POST` request to the `Yelp API`, more specifically, to the `HOLDS` endpoint.

Documentation : https://docs.developer.yelp.com/docs/endpoints-4

Code :

```
import requests
import json

api_key = someKey
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % api_key}

url='https://api.yelp.com/v3/bookings/the-house-san-francisco/holds'
params = {'time': '12:45', 'date':'2019-10-11', 'covers':'4', 'unique_id':'test'}

req=requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print(json.loads(req.text))
```

Keep getting the following error :

```
{'error': {'code': 'VALIDATION_ERROR', 'description': 'covers is a required parameter.', 'field': 'covers', 'instance': None}}
```

Bit confused on why this is happening when I'm providing the parameter. Been banging my head for a while now, yet still no progress. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the docs you provided:

[image: screenshot]

The type of "covers" should be number, but in your code it is a string:

```
params = {'time': '12:45', 'date':'2019-10-11', 'covers':'4', 'unique_id':'test'}
```

Try posting the payload as a number, as they say:

```
params = {'time': '12:45', 'date':'2019-10-11', 'covers': 4, 'unique_id':'test'}
```

(Note I removed the single quotation marks).

Comment: Already tried that -- still the same error : `{'error': {'code': 'VALIDATION_ERROR', 'description': 'covers is a required parameter.', 'field': 'covers', 'instance': None}}`

Comment: Okay, how about this:

`"Note: All parameters being sent into the holds endpoint needs to be sent as form data inside of the request body. They will not work as query parameters." ?`

You're sending the data as parameters, while they ask for form data?

Comment: Tried sending the request using `form data` in `Postman` and we got the same error again :(

Comment: I'm a bit confused, the error you posted is received from Postman or Python's requests? It says that the code of the error is 'VALIDATION_ERROR', perhaps in Postman you forgot to add authorization?

Comment: Let me clarify. First, I tried in `Python` -- didn't work kept receiving this error then checked the request in `Postman` and received the same request. No, we didn't forget to add `authorization`

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. The Python code you posted looks correct, so I believe the problem is with the request itself. As they want form data in the request, the payload should be something like: `data = {'time': '12:45', 'date'  :'2019-10-11', 'covers' : 4, 'unique_id' : 'test'}`and the request itself `res = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)` - Hope it works...